# How do I fix this SCSS compile error for the @each directive?

Tags: css, sass, less, shopify

I am creating a Shopify theme that utilizes an SCSS theme liquid. However, I keep getting this error message when it tries to compile:

> Failed to compile SCSS file.
>   Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "@each $ratio-name": expected "in", was ", $ratio-height..." on line 90 of /s/files/1/1492/9806/t/78/assets/grid.scss

I am starting to wonder if it is the way I have combined the @each string together? From my viewpoint, I wrote the code correctly, but this may be in error in the way I learned it.

Any guidance on how to fix this error would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:
I figured out Shopify uses SASS 3.2 which may not support this newer directive. Does anyone know a streamlined or "old school" way to achieve this rule?**

**MY CODE:**

```css
$ratios: (
  (ratio-16-9, 9, 16),
  (ratio-3-4, 3, 4),
  (ratio-1-1, 1, 1)
) !default;

@each $ratio-name, $ratio-height, $ratio-width in $ratios {
  .#{$ratio-name} {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    &::after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: calc((#{$ratio-height} / #{$ratio-width}) * 100%);
      width: 100%;
    }

    iframe,
    video,
    img {
      height: 100.5%;
      left: 50%;
      perspective: 1px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 100.5%;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .fit {
      font-family: 'object-fit: cover; object-position: center;';
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: center;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: May I know why you have used `!default`

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the @each loop is also supported in sass 3.2. However the destructuring feature is not. To work around this you could just use one variable in your @each loop instead of three and assign the new variables you need inside of the loop - like this:

```
$ratios: (
  (ratio-16-9, 9, 16),
  (ratio-3-4, 3, 4),
  (ratio-1-1, 1, 1)
) !default;

@each $ratio-item in $ratios {
  $ratio-name: nth($ratio-item, 1);
  $ratio-height: nth($ratio-item, 2);
  $ratio-width: nth($ratio-item, 3);

  .#{$ratio-name} {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    &::after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      height: 0;
      padding-bottom: calc((#{$ratio-height} / #{$ratio-width}) * 100%);
      width: 100%;
    }

    iframe,
    video,
    img {
      height: 100.5%;
      left: 50%;
      perspective: 1px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      width: 100.5%;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .fit {
      font-family: 'object-fit: cover; object-position: center;';
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: center;
    }
  }
}
```